# AWS S3 set object lifetime while generating presigned uri for upload

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

For example i generate upload link using GeneratePresignedUrlRequest. Is there any possibility to set the object`s (which later will be uploaded to s3 by this link) lifetime?
 I mean, it should be automatically deleted for example in 7 days since uploaded. 
So how can I do it in the step of generating upload link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify the object's lifetime via the presigned URL. What you can do is upload all the objects to a bucket that has a [lifecycle rule](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) defined that will delete them 7 days after they've been uploaded.

Comment: so is there any possibility to set this rule using java?

Comment: Yes: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/manage-lifecycle-using-java.html